# Number theory problem with possible binary

Tags: number-theory

Prove that among any seven distinct positive integers in the set $\{2, 3, 4, \ldots, 127\}$, one can find two of them, say $x$ and $y$, satisfying the inequality $1 < \frac{y}{x} < 2$.

A hint tells me to try finding what happens when I put everything in base 2, but I have gotten nothing so far.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Split our numbers into $6$ groups: 2,3; 4 to 7; 8 to 15; 16 to 31; 32 to 63; 64 to 127. Now use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: In base $2$ the numbers range from $10$ to $1111111$, so they have between $2$ and $7$ binary digits (inclusive). That’s $6$ possible lengths, and you have $7$ numbers. What happens if you divide one number of a given length by a smaller number of the same length?